# Small and large sets

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let D have small hom sets. Does this functor category Set^D have small hom-sets? I think this is not true, I mean each functor can't possibly be coded as a small set if D itself is large. I'm working within a universe.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed not true. Peter Freyd and Ross Street proved in the paper [on the size of categories](http://www.maths.soton.ac.uk/EMIS/journals/TAC/volumes/1995/n9/v1n9.pdf) that both $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{D}}$ have small hom-sets if and only if the category $\mathcal{D}$ is essentially small, so any category which has a large set of objects will give a counterexample.

Comment: To be nitpicky, any category with a large set of objects which is ALSO not equivalent to one with a small set of objects would provide a counterexample, e.g. the category of Sets (or more generally, any Grothendieck topos).

Comment: or, a discrete category with a large set of objects.

Comment: Not the first time the question has been asked. See "Is the presheaf category of a locally small category locally small?"
